# Tags not associated in OS X

Tags: macos, finder-tag

I have tags assigned to my user created text file and it wouldn't show on finder.

I have assigned, Green icon / tag (renamed to environments) to associate a text file. Tag gets assigned good. Atleast thats what i see.

But when i click on the Green tag on the sidebar of the finder, to get all files associated with green, it does not work.

I did try restarting my Mac for the settings to take effect to no avail.

Image attached.
[image]

This is in relation to this question posted here.

[Unknown tag in finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/181606/unknown-tag-in-finder)

Comment: In %, how much free space do you have? What happens when you change the sorting from `Kind` (if that's what's selected) to `Name`?

Comment: Is it only that Tag or all of them not working?

Comment: I have 85% free left on my HDD.
Even if i change sorting to any other kind, it wouldnt work.

Comment: Its just not the tag, what is in there, all others are not working too. I think tag functionality is somehow not working in mine.

Comment: I just figured out that if i do the tagging in my internal HDD, it works, but if i try to tag contents from external HDD, they dont work.

Very interesting, Any one seen this before?

Comment: Basically the following has to be done.

1. Issued sudo mdutil -i on "/Volumes/External-SSD” and got back "Indexing and searching disabled.” for external HDD. 
2. Defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true ; killall Finder (shows all file)
3. Go to hdd where indexing is not working. externalssd in my case. find locate .metadata_never_index & delete it.
4. sudo mdutil -i on "/Volumes/External-SSD” started spotlight indexing and indexes are created.
5. Tags working now.

This concludes that Tag functionality is dependant on spotlight and needs to be enabled.

Comment: stupid apple support wasted my time, blaming my external HDD. IDIOTS.

Answer (score 1):

1. Issued sudo mdutil -i on "/Volumes/External-SSD” and got back "Indexing and searching disabled.” for external HDD.
2. Defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true ; killall Finder (shows all file)
3. Go to hdd where indexing is not working. externalssd in my case. find locate .metadata_never_index & delete it.
4. sudo mdutil -i on "/Volumes/External-SSD” started spotlight indexing and indexes are created.
5. Tags working now.

This concludes that Tag functionality is dependant on spotlight and needs to be enabled.

Comment: Tag functionality (being able to tag files) is not dependent on Spotlight. _Searching_ for tags using Finder, which in turn uses Spotlight to return results, is. Your screenshot above shows the green "Environments" tag selected in Finder, which is really just a custom search or search folder where the criteria is "tag is Environments".

Comment: Sorry when spotlight functionality is not on, then you would not be able to get files tagged on to those. Try, test it.